# Calling function

Tags: fortran, computation

I don't know is this right room to ask this question of not. If not I am sorry for that.
I am new user for the fortran and  spending a lot of time for the following stuff.

I have constructed a function called "loglike" which returns a real number depending on two parameters. I want to use this function to construct a mcmc algorithm

which goes like this.

```
psi = min(0, loglike(propalpha,propbeta) - loglike(currentalpha,currentbeta))
```

where `propalpha = currentalpha + noise`, and `propbeta = currentbeta + noise`, noises are random samples from some distribution.

Now I want to use this algorithm by calling previously constructed function "loglike".

1) how can I call the function 'loglike' for new program called main program
2) how can I use this for the subroutine?

Any help is very great for me.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
module mcmc

implicit none

contains

    subroutine subru(A,B, alphaprop, betaprop)
        real, intent(in)::A,B
        real, intent(out)::alphaprop, betaprop
    end subroutine subru

    real function aloglike(A,B)
        real:: A,B,U, aloglike
        aloglike = U
    end function aloglike

end module mcmc


program  likelihood
    use mcmc

    implicit none

    real :: alpha,beta,dist1,dist2,prob1,prob2
    real:: psi,a(1000),b(1000), u1, u2,u, alphaprop, betaprop
    real, dimension(1:1):: loglike
    integer :: t,i,j,k,l
    real, dimension(1:625):: x
    real, dimension(1:625):: y
    integer, dimension(1:625):: inftime

    alpha = 0.5
    beta = 2.0

    open(10, file = 'epidemic.txt', form = 'formatted')
    do l = 1,625
       read(10,*,end = 200) x(l), y(l), inftime(l)
    enddo
200 continue

    loglike = 0.0
    do t=1,10
        do i=1,625
            if(inftime(i)==0 .or. t < (inftime(i)-1)) then
                dist1 = 0.0
                do  j = 1, 625
                    if(t >= inftime(j) .and. inftime(j)/=0)then
                        dist1 = dist1 + sqrt((x(i) - x(j))**2 + (y(i) - y(j))**2)**(-beta)
                    endif
                enddo
                prob1 = 1 - exp(-alpha * dist1)
                loglike = loglike + log(1 - prob1)
            endif

            if(inftime(i) .eq. (t+1)) then
                dist2 = 0.0
                    do k=1, 625
                    if(t >= inftime(k) .and. inftime(k)/=0) then
                        dist2 = dist2 + sqrt((x(i) - x(k))**2 + (y(i) - y(k))**2)**(-beta)
                    endif
                enddo
                prob2 = 1 - exp(-alpha * dist2)
                loglike = loglike + log(prob2)
            endif
        enddo
    enddo

    do i = 2, 1000
        a(1)= 0.0
        b(1) = 0.0
        call subru(a(i),b(i), alphaprop, betaprop)
        call random_number(u1)
        call random_number(u2)

        alphaprop = a(i-1) + (u1*0.4)-0.2
        betaprop= b(i-1) + (u2*0.4)-0.2

        if(alphaprop> 0 .and. alphaprop < 0.2 .and. betaprop > 0 .and. betaprop < 0.2)then
            psi = min(0.0,aloglike(alphaprop,betaprop)- aloglike(a(i-1),b(i-1)))
            call random_number(u)

            if(u < psi)then
                a(i)= alphaprop
                b(i) = betaprop
            else
                a(i) = a(i-1)
                b(i) = b(i-1)
            endif
        endif
    enddo

    do j = 1, 1000
        print *, A(j), A(j), LOGLIKE
    enddo

end program
```

Comment: aloglike uses variable "u", which isn't defined in that function.  It looks that you use variable "size" before it is defined.  Two suggestions: 1) start with pieces and get them working, then add more. 2) Turn on all debugging options of your compiler.  E.g., your compiler should tell you that you have declared aloglike twice.  What compilers are you using?

Comment: Which vendor's f90 compiler?   gfortran, Intel ifort, etc.?   Which operating system?

Comment: If you have loglike in a different file, prob. you don't need aloglike in this file.   Can you move it into this file so that it is in the same module?   If not, then put both filenames on the compile command: something like: "gfortran loglike.f90 myprog.f90 -o myprog.exe".   I suggest including the following options with gfortran to help you find problems with your program: -O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace.

Comment: Try writing a small part of the program and testing it, then writing more.  Probably you need to spend more time reading a book about programming, e.g., "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf and Reid.

Comment: Apparently your code is different from what you have posted.  Subroutine subru and function aloglike are incomplete.  loglike is an array of size 1 without a function definition.  If you have posted different code from what you have, we can't guess the solution to your problem.   Try the compiler debugging options, solve the problem in steps, and proceed carefully.  As a last resort, insert intermediate print statement to find out what the program is doing.

Comment: Probably you don't need aloglike.   That was a renaming of loglike suggested by wallyk to have the function typed real instead of integer via implicit typing.  It is far better not to use implicit typing in which case you don't need to rename the function.  Maybe aloglike is undefined because you don't see the reason for it.   So probably get rid of aloglike and put function loglike into the same file, into the module.  If this doesn't clear it up for you, I think that you need to read a book about Fortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general way it would look.  Note that functions return a value by assigning the result to its own name.  A `return` statement is not necessary.

```
C "loglike" is renamed "aloglike" so implicit typing uses REAL
C A type declaration could be used instead

    function aloglike (alpha, beta)
        aloglike = ... (expression which computes value)
    end

    program whateveryouwanttocallit
       ...
       propalpha = ...
       propbeta = ...
       currentalpha = ...
       currentbeta = ...
       ...
       psi = min(0, aloglike(propalpha,propbeta) - aloglike(currentalpha,currentbeta))
       print *, 'psi = ', psi

    end
```

Comment: I am sorry I could not upload my code properly. The problem I am having is how to start the main program and subroutines using the given program? So if you give the out line of the code, it will be great for me.Thanks

Comment: @David:  I did give the outline.  Just put all those lines in one file, replace the `...` with appropriate logic, compile, and run.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and most reliable technique is to place your functions and subroutines in a module and "use" that module from your main program.  This can be done in one file.  This method makes the interfaces of the procedures (functions and subroutines) known so that the compiler can check consistency between arguments in the call (actual arguments) and called (dummy arguments).   Sketch:

```
module mysubs

implicit none

contains

subroutine sub1 (xyz)
   declarations
   code
end subroutine sub1

function func2 (u)
   declarations
   code
   func2 = ...
end func2

end module mysubs

program myprog

use mysubs

implicit none

declarations...

call sub1 (xyz)

q = func2 (z)

end program myprog
```

ADDED: "implicit none" is used to disable implicit typing, which is dangerous in my opinion.  So you will need to type all of your variables, including the function name in the function. You can call the subroutines and functions from other procedures of the module -- they will automatically be known.  So you can use "func2" from "sub1", if you wish.   For entities outside of the module, such as your main program, you must "use" the module.

Comment: I put your code sample into the question.  You will want "real :: fun" in the declarations of function fun. And probably best to include loglike in the module ... obviously many missing parts from this skeleton.   Do you still have a question?

Comment: @M.B.S Can you go through the above sample code of edit 2 and tell me whats going wrong?